# How to check the count of each values repeating in a row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables. Data in the first table is:

```
ID         Username
1           Dan
2           Eli
3           Sean
4           John
```

Second Table Data:

```
user_id           Status_id
    1                   2  
    1                   3
    4                   1
    3                   2
    2                   3
    1                   1
    3                   3
    3                   3
    3                   3
    .                   .
    goes on             goes on
```

These are my both tables.

I want to find the frequency of individual users doing 'status_id'

My expected result is:

```
username     status_id(1)   status_id(2)     status_id(3)
Dan                1             1                1
Eli                0             0                1
Sean               0             1                2
John               1             0                0
```

My current code is:

```
SELECT b.username , COUNT(a.status_id)
FROM masterdb.auth_user b
left outer join masterdb.xmlform_joblist a
on a.user1_id = b.id 
GROUP BY b.username, b.id, a.status_id
```

This gives me the separate count but in a single row without mentioning which status_id each column represents

Comment: try pivot or dynamic pivot if the status has more then three values dynamic pivot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called pivot and it works in two steps:

- extracts the data for the specific field using a `CASE` statement
- aggregates the data on users, to make every field value lie on the same record for each user

```
SELECT Username, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN status_id = 1 THEN 1 END) AS status_id_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status_id = 2 THEN 1 END) AS status_id_2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status_id = 3 THEN 1 END) AS status_id_3
FROM       t2
INNER JOIN t1 
        ON t2.user_id = t1._ID
GROUP BY Username
ORDER BY Username
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qL6WAYQrAbsgyJ7Q1T33xC/0).

Note: This solution assumes that there are 3 status_id values. If you need to generalize on the amount of status ids, you would require a dynamic query. In any case, it's better to avoid dynamic queries if you can.

Comment: An alternative to the CASE expression is `count(*) filter (where status_id = 1)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you elaborate what is the filter here ?

Comment: See documentation for [Aggregate Expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES). "If FILTER is specified, then only the input rows for which the filter_clause evaluates to true are fed to the aggregate function; other rows are discarded. For your need use  multiple `filter` clauses.  So: count(\*) filter (where status_id = 1) as s1, count(\*) filter (where status_id = 2) as s2, ...